If some one believes that nothing really matters but he still seeks love
If someone believes that nothing really matters, but he still seeks love even though he thinks that even the love he seeks doesn't matter and doesn't have meaning, but he can not stop the urge of seeking love nor believing in meaning in the love he's seeking, the problem is that it seems contradictory to him and illogical. I need an answer or some kind of philosophy that helps. Forgive my ignorance if the question sounds stupid and thank you.

He is at war with himself on different levels. It's a valid question, but more likely for psychology than philosophy. The key term is integrity, in the sense of integral: to be all one thing instead of multiple things. Ego is the primary troublemaker here.

@ScottRowe Thank you so much it was really helpful

If nothing matters, why not seek love? Or why not pour applesauce on your head and go around breaking car windows? Nothing matters, so both of these options should be equally attractive to you!

@Scott Rowe Psychology is a pattern of drama. When we try to describe or analyze, rather than experience, patterns of drama, the description always reduces to philosophical assertions.  Sigmund Freud, for example, asserts that the biological (human) ego strives to become happy and remain so in this world; asserts that love makes the ego happy; and that failure to work in cooperation with others threatens the ego due to the ultimately superior forces of nature. Baruch Spinoza describes love as a feeling of pleasure accompanied by an idea of its external cause. Love also fears the loss of love.

The original intention to love, which is a rational attribute of the helpless human ego, and how this intention morphs and becomes adapted in early life, is one of the least understood ideas in human philosophy. In essence if you did not intend to love in early life then you won't be likely to seek love in adult life. And if your intention to love in early life was mixed with pain in the dramatic context then you will have distorted ideas in adult life. Prudence, the ability to govern action by the use of reason, is a tool for evil if there is no intention to love/care for others and the self.

If nothing really matters, then why not seek something you want? I don't see a conflict between those things. Nothing really matters, I want love, I seek love.

Engaging in philosophical thinking is purely human adventure.
"Seeking love" is one of the basic instincts common to most animals.
Comparing apples and oranges is possible but counterproductive.
On the other hand, the gift of love is the biggest reward in human life. You cannot find it, it is given to you (by God or the Matrix), and in most cases you have to earn it.

If "really matters" only means "will still matter to someone in a trillion years" then it's just a language issue: things matter now, but they won't matter in a trillion years. No contradiction, no problem. Go do what matters now.
On the other hand, if the claim is extended to an argument like "nothing will matter in a trillion years; if something won't matter forever then it doesn't matter now, therefore nothing matters now" then the observation that love (and not pouring applesauce on your head) matters to people now should be sufficient to falsify one or both premises.

In 1862, Emily Dickinson wrote, "The heart wants what it wants, or else it does not care".
Suggestion.  Perhaps you do care, and perhaps caring doesn't have to fear temporality.
Suggestion follow-up:  Look yourself in the eyes in the mirror and ask yourself these same questions.  Don't be shy and look away from your gaze.  Be honest.  Your opinion matters.
I think you are headed for a trip on the Love Boat.  Bon voyage.
